# Detect two phones/handset with same phone number after phone authentication/OTP

Tags: android, node.js, firebase-authentication, account-kit

If I use phone A's number to verify an app'X' on phone B. And then install app'X' on phone A and verify the app with its number, Then I have verified two handsets with same mobile number. How can I detect this on the server and restrict such operation ?
This can usually happen when the user owns both the handset/phones.

Comment: Related documentation from Google: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html also see https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html#g_manage_telephony_&_carrier_functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the IMEI Number of both phones by this code :

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String IMEI = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

and check that the IMEI Number is differ for both phones because IMEI number is unique for every device.

And you should add the following permission into your Manifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Is this a standard practice ..using Device ID ?

Comment: yes, its works and its standard practise. and if you find my answer helpful please mark it as accepted answer